# Which all SQL Server ACLs I am part of?

Tags: sql-server, acl, windows-identity

I need to know in which all SQL ACLs my Windows ID has been added to?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have ACLs in the file system sense. Need to explain more about what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure what you're asking... but here are some pointers:

- [`sys.login_token`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186740.aspx) will show all the SIDs in your login token (Windows and SQL SIDs alike)
- [`sys.fn_my_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx) will show all effective permissions you have
- [`HAS_PERM_BY_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx) will tell if you have or not a specific permission